# Can't redirect my php page to my html thank you page. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect

Here is my html code with my form. This file is named interested.html

```html
 <h1 id="title5">Write Me</h1>
     <p align="center" style="font-size:20px">If you would like to get in touch with me, please do!</p>
     <form method="post" action="contact.php">
      <fieldset>
        <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name">
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address">
        <textarea name="msg" placeholder="Your message..."></textarea>
      </fieldset>
      <input type="submit" class="Send">
    </form>
```

This is my PHP code. After the form is filled out I want my thank you page (sent.html) to show instead of this page. This file is named contact.php

```html
<?php
//redirect to thank you page
//if information is not entered properly send to error page
//submit an confirmation email to me

  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $msg = $_POST["msg"];

  echo "<pre>";
  $email_body = "";
  $email_body .= "Name " . $name . "\n";
  $email_body .= "Email " . $email . "\n";
  $email_body .= "Message " . $msg . "\n";
  echo $email_body;
  echo "</pre>";

  header("location:sent.html");

?>
```

Please help, and please let me know if I did not explain my question well enough or if more information is needed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header instruction must be called before any content returned. But you write `echo` before `header`.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Thanks for the quick reply worked perfectly.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
ob_start();
//redirect to thank you page
//if information is not entered properly send to error page
//submit an confirmation email to me

  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $msg = $_POST["msg"];

  echo "<pre>";
  $email_body = "";
  $email_body .= "Name " . $name . "\n";
  $email_body .= "Email " . $email . "\n";
  $email_body .= "Message " . $msg . "\n";
  echo $email_body;
  echo "</pre>";

  header("location:sent.html");

?>
```

Comment: works in local host but its not working on my github.io

Comment: is it github page? github not support php